# Can't Install or Unistall?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and i tried to update my Nvidia Drivers. I used the Nvidia website and selected the drivers for my 1050. After waiting for a while, the software and updates  said that i was using a manually installed Driver. I can no longer install any applications for I get a response, "Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)." When i try the fix broken install I get, "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" Ive googled this issue and have tried a lot of the options, but i cannot seem to find one that works. I am just trying to reinstall the original graphics driver, but the option is grayed out.